# Why does $2 \times 2k = 2 + 2k$ in this proof?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

I feel like this is a super simple question and I am missing something obvious.

In a proof by induction of $2^{n}>2 n$ for every positive integer $n \gt 2$, $P(k)$ is given as $2^k \gt 2k$ and the induction step is as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
2^{k+1}&=2 \times 2^{k}>2 \times 2 k \quad \text {by the induction hypothesis} \\
&=2(k+1)
\end{aligned}
$$

I can see why $2^{k+1}=2^1 \times 2^k = 2 \times 2^k$.

I don't see why $2(k+1) = 2 \times 2k$. Wouldn't it be $2k+2$? Why or how does this multiplication get changed to an addition?

(Proof is on this page halfway down page 2 https://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mathcentre-proof2.pdf)

Comment: Probably it should be $2 \times 2k > 2(k+1)$.

Comment: Instead of $=2(k+1)$, it should be $>2(k+1)$. Then the proof makes sense.

Comment: What GEdgar and Adam Rubinson have said is correct. The proof on the link you have provided is missing a step. The statement $2(2k) = 4k = 2(k+1)$ cannot be true since subtracting by $2k$ on both sides would give $2k=2$, which is not true for all $k$.

Answer (score 1):

In the induction step, you should say

Let $ k>2 $ such that $ 2^k>2k $.

$$2^k>2k \implies 2^{k+1}>2\times 2k$$

$$\implies 2^{k+1}>2k+2k$$
$$\implies 2^{k+1}>2k+2$$
$$\implies 2^{k+1}>2(k+1)$$

Comment: Okay, I think I was misreading. Both of these answers make it clear.

Comment: @RobertW You were not misreading. The source just contains an error.

Comment: @SaudMolaib ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

By the induction hypothesis, $2^k > 2k.$ This implies that $2\times 2^k > 2 \times 2k,$ i.e. that $2^{k+1} > 2(k+1).$

Comment: Okay,I think I was misreading. Both of these answers make it clear.